# Camera Flutter Plugin Cannot Capture

Tags: flutter, camera

i cannot capture an image when the torch was on. seems like takePicture() doesn't return anything. i try to print some string after await those function and it doesn't printed.

this my screen/components to capture camera using camera plugin.

i place my code in the link below

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/billbull21/Code-Hosting/main/custom_camera_component.dart

Comment: Please post a snippet of the code, So that we can look into the issue.

Comment: @Mukul - i was updating my question.